# Insert data as first item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox which binds data from the database.  It gets the data correctly but I want the first item  I tried but I could not so how can I do that? and where in code page?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the first item from the combobox?

```
Object firstItem = comboBox.Items[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this,

```
object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;   
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
```

This will work.You should first create the `selected item` object then use it.
See here : [[ComboBox.SelectedItem Property]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx).

Feel free to tell me if I am wrong.